# Using Sed to Append Lines to File During Vagrant Provisioning

Tags: ruby, linux, string

I'm currently using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to set up a development machine running Ubuntu. I want to add a few lines to my `.profile` that add directories to my `$PATH` variable, using `sed`. To this end, I added these lines to my machine's `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline:
    "sudo sed -i \'$ a if [ -d \\\"/usr/local/lib\\\" ]; then\n    PATH=\\\"/usr/local/lib:$PATH\\\"\nfi\' /home/vagrant/.profile"
```

To the best of my knowledge and testing, I've escaped all the characters needed to have Vagrant run this valid shell command:

```
sudo sed -i '$ a if [ -d \"/usr/local/lib\" ]; then\n    PATH=\"/usr/local/lib:$PATH\"\nfi' /home/vagrant/.profile
```

Which adds these lines to my `.profile`:

```
if [ -d "usr/local/lib" ]; then
    PATH="usr/local/lib:$PATH"
fi
```

However, when I do a `vagrant up` I get the following error when it tries to run the command:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: sed: -e expression #1, char 44: extra characters after command
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere in my `Vagrantfile` code, or is there something else going wrong here?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat Well, until reading the link you posted, I had always thought Stack Overflow was the more generic site, and this site was for more specific stuff. Guess I know for the future now.

Comment: There is a discussion on the "stdin: is not a tty" error at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1673, with suggested workarounds.

Comment: @Victor I don't believe that is the issue unless there's some strange interaction I'm unaware of, since I've been getting "stdin: is not a tty" the whole time I've been using Vagrant. I've also successfully used `sed` in Vagrantfiles to append much simpler strings to files, so I have no idea why it would suddenly stop working. My best guess is that I have a subtle syntax error that I can't seem to find. Should I remove the "stdin: is not a tty" line because it's irrelevant, or is it actually causing the problem somehow?

Comment: @ChristopherSheaf, you are right, "stdin: is not a tty" line is irrelevant. Could you try escaping "\n" too? I.e. "sudo sed -i \'$ a if [ -d \\\"/usr/local/lib\\\" ] then\\n    PATH=\\\"/usr/local/lib:$PATH\\\"\\nfi\' /home/vagrant/.profile"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix "sed: -e expression #1, char 44: extra characters after command", escape \n, that is add another backslash to all \n:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline:
"sudo sed -i \'$ a if [ -d \\\"/usr/local/lib\\\" ] then\\n    PATH=\\\"/usr/local/lib:$PATH\\\"\\nfi\' /home/vagrant/.profile"
```

Comment: That was the issue. Seems I was confused whether I needed the literal newline character in the Vagrantfile string or the sed string. Do you happen to know if there's a way I could have used raw string literals in this scenario? To the best of my knowledge, there's no way that can help with nested strings like this.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about what you mean by "a way I could have used raw string literals". But you could use { config.vm.provision "shell", path: } instead of { config.vm.provision "shell", inline: } and pass to it the path to the script containing the sed command without additional escaping: { sudo sed -i '$ a if [ -d \"/usr/local/lib\" ]; then\n    PATH=\"/usr/local/lib:$PATH\"\nfi' }